# modify yolov5 v7.0'yolov5s6.yaml ,but got an error: RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 3. Got 42 and 44

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, concatenation, runtime-error, yolov5

I attempted to modify the YOLOv5s6 v7.0 model by editing the yolov5s6.yaml file located in models/hub/yolov5s6.yaml. Specifically, I made changes to the 14th, 18th, and 22nd concatenate layers and added an upsample layer after SPPF.

When I run yolo.py, the model prints output successfully. However, I encounter an error at the end of the first epoch during training.

Can I get your assistance with this issue? Thank you.

**the backbone and the head code:**
note:depth_multiple:1    width_mutiple:0.5

```
backbone:
  # [from, number, module, args]
  [[-1, 1, Conv, [64, 6, 2, 2]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 2]],
   [-1, 1, C3, [128]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 2]],
   [-1, 2, C3, [256]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [512, 3, 2]],
   [-1, 3, C3, [512]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [768, 3, 2]],
   [-1, 1, C3, [768]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [1024, 3, 2]],
   [-1, 1, C3, [1024]],
   [-1, 1, SPPF, [1024, 5]],
   [-1, 1, nn.Upsample, [None, 2, 'nearest']]
  ]

head:
  [[-1, 1, Conv, [512, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, nn.Upsample, [None, 2, 'nearest']],
   [[-1, 6], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, C3, [512, False]],

   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, nn.Upsample, [None, 2, 'nearest']],
   [[-1, 4], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, C3, [256, False]],

   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, nn.Upsample, [None, 2, 'nearest']],
   [[-1, 2], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, C3, [128, False]],

   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 2]],
   [[-1, 21], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, C3, [256, False]],

   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 2]],
   [[-1, 17], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, C3, [512, False]],

   [-1, 1, Conv, [512, 3, 2]],
   [[-1, 13], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, C3, [1024, False]],

   [[24, 27, 30, 33], 1, Detect, [nc, anchors]],
  ]
```

it runs successfully on yolo.py.

**the error when running train.py:**

Starting training for 75 epochs...

```
  Epoch    GPU_mem   box_loss   obj_loss   cls_loss  Instances       Size
   0/74     0.902G    0.02716   0.004114          0          0        640: 100%|██████████| 187/187 [00:55<00:00,  3.39it/s]
             Class     Images  Instances          P          R      mAP50   mAP50-95:   0%|          | 0/12 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\pycharmproject\learn\yolov5-master\yolov5-featurefusion\yolov5-master-changeneck\train.py", line 649, in 
main(opt)
File "F:\pycharmproject\learn\yolov5-master\yolov5-featurefusion\yolov5-master-changeneck\train.py", line 538, in main
train(opt.hyp, opt, device, callbacks)
File "F:\pycharmproject\learn\yolov5-master\yolov5-featurefusion\yolov5-master-changeneck\train.py", line 361, in train
results, maps, _ = validate.run(data_dict,
File "D:\anaconda3\envs\yolov5\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\grad_mode.py", line 27, in decorate_context
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "F:\pycharmproject\learn\yolov5-master\yolov5-featurefusion\yolov5-master-changeneck\val.py", line 210, in run
preds, train_out = model(im) if compute_loss else (model(im, augment=augment), None)
File "D:\anaconda3\envs\yolov5\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
File "F:\pycharmproject\learn\yolov5-master\yolov5-featurefusion\yolov5-master-changeneck\models\yolo.py", line 209, in forward
return self._forward_once(x, profile, visualize)  # single-scale inference, train
File "F:\pycharmproject\learn\yolov5-master\yolov5-featurefusion\yolov5-master-changeneck\models\yolo.py", line 121, in _forward_once
x = m(x)  # run
File "D:\anaconda3\envs\yolov5\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
File "F:\pycharmproject\learn\yolov5-master\yolov5-featurefusion\yolov5-master-changeneck\models\common.py", line 346, in forward
return torch.cat(x, self.d)

**RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 3. Got 42 and 44 (The offending index is 0)**

Comment: anyone know this? please~